# Generate Tab URL With Pure Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, button-overrides

I have a custom Object called "Related Professionals" and I overrided the 'New' button to auto populate the "Name" Field with the Default text.

This is the New button Override VF page :

```
<apex:page standardController="RelatedProfessionals__c" action="{!URLFOR($Action.RelatedProfessionals__c.New, null,[Name='Default',retURL='/a16/o'],true)}" >
</apex:page>
```

I don't want the retURL to be hardcoded like that(since Id of custom object wouldn't not be consistent between sandbox's).

What options do I have on Visualforce page to not hard code that ID?

*I don't have a controller for this Object and would like to avoid using one if possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `$ObjectType` [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_objecttype_schema_objects_reference.htm) to get the key prefix:

```
retUrl='/' & $ObjectType.RelatedProfessionals__c.keyPrefix + '/o'
```

---

You can't use it here, but with some SObjects, you can use the `$Action` [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm) to get the tab:

```
retUrl=URLFOR($Action.Case.Tab)
```

Unfortunately, the only supported types are:

> - Ad group
> - Campaign
> - Case
> - Contact
> - Contract
> - Google campaign
> - Keyword
> - Lead
> - Opportunity
> - Product
> - Search phrase
> - SFGA version
> - Solution
> - Text ad

Comment: @Nick Glad I could help!